# mod_rewrite numbers for dynamic JS

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to call a URL that looks like this:

http://mydomain.com/123456.js

and have mod_rewrite output this:

http://mydomain.com/js/js.php?id=123456

My current attempt is this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\.js$ /js/js.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming your htaccess is in root directory, i can see nothing wrong.

The only problem i could imagine would be the leading slash, depending on your Apache version.
You can try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)\.js$ /js/js.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Also, it would be better to forbid access to your php file and redirect it to your pretty url:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/js/js\.php\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.js? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)\.js$ /js/js.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the initial / in the url. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)\.js$ /js/js.php?id=$1 [L]
```